# ggplot geom_rect() error "object not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a `geom_rect()`. Why do I receive an `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Month' not found`? If I run `df$Month` in my console the object is there:

```
df$Month
#> [1] 2019-01 2019-02 2019-03
#> Levels: 2019-01 2019-02 2019-03
```

Here's my code block:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Month = factor(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03")), 
             Value = c(4, 9, 7))

ggplot(df, aes(Month, Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(data = 
              data.frame(xmin = min(as.integer(df$Month)) - 0.5,
                         xmax = max(as.integer(df$Month)) + 0.5,
                         ymin = min(df$Value),
                         ymax = max(df$Value)),
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.2, fill = "green")

#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Month' not found
```

Comment: I think you need to unmap x and y, by setting `x = NULL, y = NULL` in `geom_rect`, but re-reading the docs I feel like they could be clearer about this. They sort of imply that `geom_rect` doesn't accept x/y at all.

Comment: It seems that your desired result should utilize `theme()` not `geom_rect()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have an extra step of setting up a dataframe in `geom_rect` which coincide with data in `ggplot`. Simply provide your max and min values to `geom_rect` and it works:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Month, Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(as.integer(Month)) - 0.5, 
                xmax = max(as.integer(Month)) + 0.5, 
                ymin = min(Value), 
                ymax = max(Value)),
            alpha = 0.2/nrow(df), fill = "green")
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Month, Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(data = 
              data.frame(xmin = min(as.integer(df$Month)) - 0.5,
                         xmax = max(as.integer(df$Month)) + 0.5,
                         ymin = min(df$Value),
                         ymax = max(df$Value)),
            aes(x = NULL,y = NULL,xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.2, fill = "green")
```

by unmapping the inherited x/y aesthetics from the top ggplot call. It's understandable that this might be confusing, though, since the description in `?geom_rect` sorta kinda implies that `geom_rect` isn't looking for those aesthetics at all.

Comment: `inherit.aes = F` also works instead of setting `x` and `y` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to return your desired result by calling `df` in `geom_line()` after `gemo_rect()`. However leaving the *Month* field as is returned the error: **Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale**.
I worked around this by wrapping `as.integer()` around *Month*.

```
ggplot() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(data = 
              data.frame(xmin = min(as.integer(df$Month)) - 0.5,
                         xmax = max(as.integer(df$Month)) + 0.5,
                         ymin = min(df$Value),
                         ymax = max(df$Value)),
            aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.2, fill = "green") + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(as.integer(Month), Value, group = 1))
```

[image]

You might have to clean up your x-axis label but it achieves desired outcome!