# Unexpected Behavior of transparency parameter in geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha-transparency

This is a follow up to this question: [ggplot geom_rect() error “object not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301759/ggplot-geom-rect-error-object-not-found)

I was answering this question that I noticed a strange behavior of `alpha` in `geom_rect()`. It seems when you pass the data from `ggplot()` to `geom_rect()`, it affects the *"effctiveness"* of `alpha`, which leads to the color be less transparent. Look at the output of the two plotting options from the two answers provided to the aforementioned question for clarification.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Month = factor(c("2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03")), 
             Value = c(4, 9, 7))


joran <- ggplot(df, aes(Month, Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(data = 
              data.frame(xmin = min(as.integer(df$Month)) - 0.5,
                         xmax = max(as.integer(df$Month)) + 0.5,
                         ymin = min(df$Value),
                         ymax = max(df$Value)),
            aes(x = NULL,y = NULL,xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            alpha = 0.2, fill = "green")


M_M <- ggplot(df, aes(Month, Value, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(as.integer(Month)) - 0.5, 
                xmax = max(as.integer(Month)) + 0.5, 
                ymin = min(Value), 
                ymax = max(Value)),
            alpha = 0.2, fill = "green")
```

I can replicate Joran's plot by using `alpha=0.1`. Just to be clear, I just plotted these on my machine, and these are not the same screenshots from that question.

I wonder what causes this behavior.

```
Joran's Plot:
```

```
My Plot:
```

Comment: Your plot is essentially the same rectangle repeated 3 times (one for each row of your dataset), so the transparency adds up. You can check this with `layer_data(M_M, 2L)`.

Comment: *Note:* The other thread provides more insight into this matter.